# Points disappeared not rendering

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, point, rendering

Using QGIS 3.10 - new data points are disappearing after clicking on save. Layer is digitising points (park assets) which have been identified from field capture. Up until yesterday April 17, 2020, all data points were appearing, and then after changing the style (colour) for one asset type, all have now disappeared.

The point appears in the attribute table, but not symbolized on the map. I am using categories for my symbols.

Example - Each of the grey squares should have a point symbol in the centre - as per the Attribute table. Note - disregard the brown dots this is our field capture layer

[image]

I have tried following above responses to saving a new shapefile - this has not changed the issue.

Why are all points not rendering?

[image]

re @she-weeds screenshot of styling details - attached, these have all been "classified" with symbols for each asset type which relate to the park asset type

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to GIS.SE! Could you share what category you are currently using for your style? Maybe a screenshot of the styling details? Your features won't render if they have a value for that category which doesn't appear in the symbol list - for example if you categorised by Park_Cat and have symbols for 'City', 'Street', etc but not 'Neighbourhood', and you don't have a symbol for all other values (which is usually generated by default), those points you've highlighted simply won't appear.

Comment: I've experienced something similar when I inadvertantly applied a filter (e.g. "last_name" = 'Smith') to the layer being digitized.  When I subsequently digitized a feature with "lastname" = 'Jones' it immediately disappeared from the screen due to the filter.  But Jones was still added to the layer, viewable in the attribute table.

Comment: @she_weeds attached is screenshot of styling details

Comment: @EricH thanks for the additional details. You can include extra info in your original question, it doesn't go in an answer - I've edited your post accordingly. It seems like the value in your attribute table for 'Park Point' (`Exercise Equipment`) is not represented in the list of values for your Categorized symbology, but you also have two symbols for 'all other values' - at the top and the bottom. Can you try deleting one of those or enabling both to be visible and see if that makes your points show up on the canvas?